# Accepting an image in script

Tags: javascript, html

How would I edit this so it accepts the image when put in form all other options work just the image not uploading to server or database.

Please could someone help I have looked around and can't find anything that I understand,could someone possibly add a bit of code to this?

Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("#Submit").click(function() {

var url = "../AdsCreate/CreateCar.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: $("#myForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
   success: function(html){ $("#right").html(html); }
 });

return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `<input type="file"` gets skipped when performing the `.serialize()` on the form.

It's possible to [upload files with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), but far easier to just do it within the form:

```
<form action="../AdsCrease/CreateCar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<input type="file" name="myfile" ... />
...
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I have a form that javascript processes the form and loads the page into a div so goes in a certain part of page, The form works with everything other than the image upload to server and to database which is what I need.

Comment: how would i change the serialize coz I need that part above to make page in a certain div when it goes to process the form.

Comment: You can still process the form with JavaScript and then run .submit() on the form to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: You could make the form submit into a hidden iframe. Just an idea

Comment: what you have done up above will load the whole url i need it to load in a certain div. way you have said works but its not the way it needs to be done if you know what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on `.serialize` clearly states that file upload is not supported (and indeed you need a `multipart/form-data` POST submission for uploads, it's not just a query string).

Right before the "example" sections you can find:

> Data from file select elements is not serialized.

Comment: I have a form that up top makes it so when fill out form and click submit it processes that page as you can see above, now all work when use the form other than the image to server and to database but you say can't be serialized, So what would I change that part too??